# Sorting an Array numerically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

**Hello,**

i am new to stackoverflow and coding so I hope you don't mind me asking such a trivial question.

I learned that sorting an array numerically is done as follows.
I am also aware of the simpler ES6 version.

```js
var ax = [], bx = [];

function sortNumber (a, b) {
    ax.push(a);
    bx.push(b);
    return a-b;
}

var numArray = [140000, 104, 99, 2];
numArray.sort(sortNumber);

console.log('array=' + numArray);
console.log('a=' + ax);
console.log('b=' + bx);
```

What i don't understand is, why for example in my Code-Example in the *sortNumber function*

**a = [140000, 104, 140000, 104, 99] and b = [99, 99, 2, 2, 2]** ?

Can someone tell my how a and b are determined?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that's what's happening. How did you determine those values for `a` and `b`?

Comment: `a` and `b` don't have those values. Try to console.log in the sort function `console.log('a:',a,'b:',b)`. How did you come up with those values ?

Comment: I'm curious what browser / JavaScript engine you're using that gives you those values...? It doesn't seem to be a current version of V8 (Chrome), SpiderMonkey (Firefox), or ChakraCore in either Edge or IE11.

Comment: Yes I determined these values using console.log() on playcode.io in firefox. But as i learned through the answers here, these values are randomly selected and can differ from JavaScript engine to JavaScript engine.

Comment: @laines - They're not *randomly* selected. They're very carefully selected by the `sort` implementation. I don't see the values you've shown with Firefox, but we may be using different versions. `sort` has changed relatively recently in more than one JavaScript engine to become a *stable* sort (stable = elements that are equivalent aren't moved relative to each other).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - Thanks for the clarification! I was using the online javascript editor on playcode.io on Firefox 69.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone tell my how a and b are determined?

It's entirely up to the JavaScript engine's implementation of `sort`. All that [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort) tells us is that they'll be entries from the array that need to be compared so the `sort` algorithm can do its job.

If you like, you can see V8's implementation [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/4b9b23521e6fd42373ebbcb20ebe03bf445494f9/third_party/v8/builtins/array-sort.tq), which is a variation of a [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). (V8 is the JavaScript engine used in Chromium, Chrome, Brave, and Node.js.)

I should note that V8 doesn't use the values for `a` and `b` that are shown in your question, it uses `104`, `99`, and `2` for `a` and `140000`, `104`, and `99` for `b`.

You can see which ones the JavaScript engine in your current browser uses here:

```js
var avalues = [];
var bvalues = []
function sortNumber (a, b) {
    console.log("a = " + a + ", b = " + b);
    avalues.push(a);
    bvalues.push(b);
    return a-b;
}

var numArray = [140000, 104, 99, 2];
numArray.sort(sortNumber);
console.log("done, result:", numArray.join(", "));

console.log("a values: ", avalues.join(", "));
console.log("b values: ", bvalues.join(", "));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your question is how this sorting function is working.

1. Sort functions requires comparison function (Like on what basis you need to sort the array. It can be anything)
2. Above in sortNumber function, a and b are nothing but the two values of the numArray. 
   Example - when you call `numArray.sort(sortNumber)`; it will call on all the elements of the array with each other (You care comparing each element).
   if `a - b > 0`, a is greater than b.
   if `a - b < 0`, b is greater than a.
   if `a - b = 0`, both are equal. 
   This condition will get checked on all the elements [140000, 104, 99, 2].

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I simply use lodash for such cases.

```
_.sortBy([140000, 104, 99, 2]) // => [2, 99, 104, 140000]
```